c# tablelayoutpanel setrowspan not working
I have this piece of code:
CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Outset;
RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle() { SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize });
RowCount = 0;
ColumnCount= 1;
Controls.Clear();
TextBox SomeTextBox = new TextBox();
SomeTextBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
SomeTextBox.Enter += new EventHandler(txtBox1_Enter);
SomeTextBox.Leave += new EventHandler(txtBox1_Leave);
SomeTextBox.Enabled = true;
SomeTextBox.Text= "";
Controls.Add(SomeTextBox, j * 4 + 1, i);
SetColumnSpan(SomeTextBox, VisualSettings.ColSpan);
SetRowSpan(SomeTextBox, VisualSettings.RowSpan);
int n = SetRowSpan(SomeTextBox)

This is a part of a form maker and full code is more complicated than can be copied here.
Problem is that:
SetColumnSpan works as expected.
SetRowSpan changes rowspan of control and n returns the new value.
but in rendered form, rows are not merged.
Update: I had a long conversation with Microsoft Copilot regarding the matter. When I set both Dock and Anchor Properties of control to non, then control is centered in merged area, some signs of being alive, but definitely doesnt grow the control to fill the merged area. Then I received some suggestions mostly related to WPF, like setting verticalalignment property, which is not available in winforms, and the final suggestion was to override the OnPaint of control to handle this situation.
Is this always so hard?
